# Test all soap endpoint api with Wizdler chrome extenssion

Tags: magento2, api, soap, soap-api-v2, webapi

We can check rest api with all the parameter detail from swagger so I would be highly appreciated if you guys have tested SOAP api with any tool then please guide me.

I have installed Wizdler chrome extenssion but don't know how to use it with magento2 SOAP api.

In which Url I can get all the SOAP endpoint xml definition and make compatible to run it with Wizdler

All services like this URL::
[Dummy Soap API](http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?wsdl)

Answer (score 2):

**Boomerang** is the simple and free chrome extension for test SOAP API: [Boomerang - SOAP & REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/boomerang-soap-rest-clien/eipdnjedkpcnlmmdfdkgfpljanehloah?hl=en)

---

**How To Use:**

Take an example WSDL URL: http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?wsdl

**Step 1:** Right-click on the boomerang icon at the top right corner.

**Step 2:** Now click on `Open legacy app`

[image]

**Step 3:** Now click on the `Create a Service` button

**Step 4:** Add WSDL URL and service name and click on `Add` button

[image]

**Step 5:** Now you can see all available endpoints at the left sidebar section

**Step 6:** Click on any endpoint and `Create request` to test the API

[image]

**Step 7:** You can see sample request parameters. Change the values and click on the `Send` button to check the response

[image]

Here is the sample response:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Prince but how can we pass Magento token in this request to get a response.

Comment: like if i would like to use magento `customerCustomerRepositoryV1`  and method like `customerCustomerRepositoryV1GetById` how would it be in this extenssion.if you can provide magento soap eg. then would be great

Answer (score 0):

I only used [SoapUI tool](https://www.soapui.org/docs/soap-and-wsdl/) for soap calls on m1, but m2 should be no different, as long as you know what the request should look like.

Same if you want to use [Postman tool](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/supported-api-frameworks/making-soap-requests/).

**The link to the WSDL containing the list of all endpoints is** (just replace *'<magento_host>'* with your hostname):

```
http://<magento_host>/soap/default?wsdl_list=1
```

Whichever tool you will end up using, you will have to first make an [authentication call](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html) based on integration tokens.

Comment: Yes but there is no documentation like rest.i.e which parameter do we need to pass along with api call